# Здравствйте, мне нужно убирать символ из начала строки

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть например массив : let a = [`*/-+=!`], есть строка: var a = `+-*dd`, как мне убирать из начала строки символы, находящиеся в let до тех пор, пока не начнутся другие символы? т.е было +-dd, а должно быть dd

Answer (score 0):

UPD: вообще-то стоило имена для переменных подобрать разные, потому что тогда выведет ошибку типа `SyntaxError: Identifier 'arr' has already been declared` =/

```js
let arr = ['*', '/', '-', '+', '=', '!']
var s = '+-*dd'

while (arr.includes(s[0])) { // пока в массиве есть первый символ,
  s = s.substring(1) // удаляем его из строки через substring
}

console.log(s) // dd
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @tysik пожалуйста; не забудьте закрыть данный вопрос, чтобы мёртвым не валялся, если  он решён :)